# Converting JSON to Datatable

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

In trying to convert the following json to a DataTable, I get this error:

**Error:** Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

```
var prettyJson = "{
  "AAPL": {
    "390": [
      {
        "root": "AAPL",
        "expiry": "2024-06-21T00:00:00",
      }
    ]
  }
}"

var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(prettyJson);
```

Comment: Why do you think that should be convertble to a DataTable, it doesn't conform to the spec https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm You would want an root object with each property being an array, you have it doubly nested.

Answer (score 0):

you have to flat your json object

```
DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(prettyJson, new ToDataTableConverter());

public class ToDataTableConverter : JsonConverter<DataTable>
{
    public override DataTable ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DataTable existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var rows = new JArray(JObject.Load(reader).Properties()
                       .SelectMany(x => GetRows(x.Values())));

        return rows.ToObject<DataTable>();
    }

    private JArray GetRows(IEnumerable<JToken> val)
    {
        var list = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (JProperty jo in val)
        {
            var key = jo.Name;
            foreach (JObject o in jo.Value)
            {
                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("key", key));
                list.Add(o);
            }
        }
        return new JArray(list);
    }


    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DataTable value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

output

```
[{"key":"390","root":"AAPL","expiry":"2024-06-21T00:00:00"}]
```